# How to send app push when the app installed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification, mobilestudio

did anyone knows how to send a push once a new user install the app instantly?

The only idea I have now is to refresh the filter hourly and scan for new user to send push msg.

Is there any other idea?

Or shall design in app instead of SFMC?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Journey that monitors MobilePush Demographics for a `TAG` or `Attribute` value sent from the device.